# problems puling data out of django database and testing it

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

really sorry but a complete beginner here with Django and Python. I am trying to pull some data out of a database so I can assert against it in the testing faze but I am having problems understanding how to get the data out of the model. Any help would be appreciated.

My code:

Models.py

```
class CurrentAccountState(AccountState):
    enable_personal_profile = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class CurrentAccountSetting(TimestampedModel):
    ACCOUNT_SEND_TO_OPTIONS = (
        ("buyer", _("Receipt sent to the buyer")),
        ("payment_profile_contact", _("Receipt sent to payment profile contact")),
    )

    account_state = models.ForeignKey(
        CurrentAccountState, related_name="account_settings", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    payment_profile_id = models.CharField(max_length=36)
    send_to = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=SEND_TO_OPTIONS, default="buyer")
```

views.py

```
 @action(detail=True, methods=["post"])
    def update_state(self, request, pk=None):
        integration = AccountServiceManager.get_by_name(str(pk))
        if not account:
            raise Http404()

        return Response("", status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

test update_state.py

```
    def test_update_state(self):
        user = self.admin_user
        self.client.force_login(user)
        account = AccountFactory(
            name="account name", enabled=True, provider=str_to_kebab_case("account name")
        )

        payload = {
            "enable_personal_profile": True,
            "payment_profile_settings": [
                {
                    "payment_profile_id": "Something",
                    "send_to": "buyer",
                },
                {
                    "payment_profile_id": "Something else",
                    "send_to": "payment_profile_contact",
                }
            ]
        }
        response = self.client.post(f"{self.url}/account/update_state", data=json.dumps(payload), content_type="application/json")
        assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_200_OK

        account_account = CurrentAccountSetting.objects.all()
        assert len(account_account) == 1
        assert account_account.enable_personal_payment_profile is True
```

What I am struggling with is understanding how I can pull the data out of the actual database so I can make assertions in the test. Currently the len(account_account) fails with saying I have an empty array coming from the queryset[]. Which makes sense as I haven't added anything to the views yet. But how could I actually get that data to the views?

Comment: `request.data`.

Comment: thank you @WillemVanOnsem. I can see that this does get the data to the views, however I am still struggling to understand why the assert len() in the test file is still returning queryset [] ? How can I make sure that the test can access this data?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `AccountFactory` creates a `CurrentAccountSetting` object for you:

Maybe its because you haven't run `account.save()` after line 4 in `test_update_state()`. Or you could use [create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#create).

If not, the issue is that you haven't created a `CurrentAccountSetting` object anywhere in that flow.

Also in your last line of code you probably want to get the item out of the array!

`assert account_account[0].enable_personal_payment_profile`

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I do not have a CurrentAccountSetting object in this flow. But my idea was to pull it straight out of the models db. Is this not possible?

Comment: Does the database already have items in it? in that case it could be that your test environment settings are not connecting to your usual database. This is probably for the best, as you dont really want your tests messing with your real data. Its always a good idea to make a bunch of objects to use in your test!

Comment: I got this working now, thank you. That was the solution as I didn't actually have an object to test and it was returning and empty queryset. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: awesome! glad i was able to help